# spring boot 1.3.5 form:errors not showing for jsp

Tags: validation, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am upgrading a spring-mvc web app from spring 4.X to be a spring boot war.

The page serves, the form is posted, the validation is executed (and records an error) but the jsp does show any errors in form:errors

THe same jsp works fine outside of spring-boot.

To be sure I'm setting my spring boot jsp app correctly I've simply added a form post to the existing "spring-boot-sample-web-jsp" (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.3.x/spring-boot-samples )

Here is the model object

```
  package sample.jsp;
  import java.io.Serializable;
  public class EmailHolderPageModel implements Serializable {
    private String emailAddress;

    public EmailHolderPageModel() {
        super();
    }

    public EmailHolderPageModel(String emailAddress) {
        super();
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }


    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

}
```

Here is the server side:

```
@Autowired
private EmailSaveValidator emailSaveValidator;

@RequestMapping("/saveEmail.html")
public ModelAndView processEmail(@ModelAttribute("myModel") EmailHolderPageModel pageModel, BindingResult result){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = null;

    emailSaveValidator.validate(pageModel, result);

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("enterEmail");
        EmailHolderPageModel pm = new EmailHolderPageModel("");
        modelAndView.addObject("myModel", pm);
        System.err.println("!!!Failed Validation!!!");

    } else {

        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("thankyou");
        ThankyouPageModel thankYoupageModel = new ThankyouPageModel();
        modelAndView.addObject("thankyouModel", thankYoupageModel);
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Here is the validator

```
@Component
public class EmailSaveValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class candidate) {
        return EmailHolderPageModel.class.isAssignableFrom(candidate);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "emailAddress", "emailRequired", "required field");

    }
}
```

Here is the jsp (truncated a little because stackoverflow is getting confused)

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>test entering email</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form commandName="myModel" method="POST" action="saveEmail.html" >
        <form:errors path="emailAddress"  htmlEscape="false" />
        <div id="formIntro">
            <spring:message  text="enter email address" />
            <p><strong><label>
                <spring:message  text="email address:" /> </label><form:input path="emailAddress" size="35" maxlength="200"/>
                </label>
            </strong></p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

The pom file is (unmodified from spring-boot-sample-web-jsp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-web-jsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Web JSP Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Web JSP Sample</description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>



    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

==============

And the solution is do not create a new model object on error (though works fine when not a spring boot app):

```
@RequestMapping("/saveEmail.html")
public ModelAndView processEmail(@ModelAttribute("myModel") EmailHolderPageModel pageModel, BindingResult result){

    ModelAndView modelAndView = null;

    emailSaveValidator.validate(pageModel, result);

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("enterEmail");
        // !! SOLUTION !!
        // DO NOT CREATE A NEW MODEL OBJECT
        // !! SOLUTION !!
        // EmailHolderPageModel pm = new EmailHolderPageModel("");
        modelAndView.addObject("myModel", pageModel);
        System.err.println("!!!Failed Validation!!!");

    } else {

        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("thankyou");
        ThankyouPageModel thankYoupageModel = new ThankyouPageModel();
        modelAndView.addObject("thankyouModel", thankYoupageModel);
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: I haven't been using Boot, but you can try enabling the debug logging on the core spring classes and seeing whether it sheds any light

Answer (score 0):

You commandName should be exacty the name of your model class: eg.

```
public class EmailHolderPageModel{}...
```

And in your controller any function:

```
public ModelAndView anythink(@Valid EmailHolderPageModel email...)
```

So, in you jsp form should be:

```
<form:form commandName="emailHolderPageModel" />...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tiago, but in my case it was solved by returning the same model object that was passed in.  Maybe your solution would not have necessitated that though :)